# A string is required here error

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I solve an error saying "A string is required here"

```
IF {RECEIVED AMOUNT} <= 0
THEN "CANCELLED"
ELSE {RECEIVED AMOUNT}
```

Comment: Are both of your outputs String type?

Comment: No,both are numeric type

Comment: Are you sure? That would mean "CANCELLED" is a number.

Comment: NO,{RECEIVED AMOUNT} is numeric,if that fails i need to print "cancelled" on report

Comment: Good. So if you have a *numeric* type, but the function requires a *string* type, what do you need to do to the numeric value?

Answer (score 2):

Cast `{RECEIVED AMOUNT}` to string. Try using the `ToText()` function:

```
IF {RECEIVED AMOUNT} <= 0 THEN "CANCELLED" ELSE ToText({RECEIVED AMOUNT})
```